# Can you transfer all data from an old account to a new account?

Tags: psn

I find it annoying that you cant change your PSN ID, so i´ve created a new account and was hoping there was some way you could transfer your data from the old account to the new one

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately.  All games, trophies and other data is tied directly to your account.